# From a family of projective curves to a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces

Suppose that
 $$\mathcal F:\;(X^3+Y^3+Z^3)\lambda+Z^2X\mu=0$$ 
is a family of projective plane curves parameterized by $(\lambda:\mu)\in\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$.
This family of curves forms a surface $S$; is there a way to obtain some equations defining the surface $S$?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The surface lives naturally in $\mathbb P^2 \times \mathbb P^1 \subseteq \mathbb P^5$.

As a surface in $\mathbb P^2 \times \mathbb P^1$, the equation is the same equation as you wrote.

You can embed it in $\mathbb P^5$ via the Segre embedding, and then the equations are given by the minors of a $2 \times 2$-matrix together with your original equation (in the new variables obtained by the Segre embedding).